# PHP empty: take a single 0 as a string only?

Tags: php, string

I want to take a single`0` as a string only for db injection but not `00` or `0000` as string.

```
$post["content"] = '00';

if (empty($post["content"]) && $post["content"] !== '0') 
{
     echo "this field must not be empty!";
}
```

It does not return it as an error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!trim()` instead:

```
<?php
$post["content"] = '00';


if ($post["content"] !== '0' && !trim($post["content"], '0')) 
{
    echo "this field must not be empty!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong.

```
$single ="0";
$double = "00";

var_dump(empty($single)); // true
var_dump(empty($double)); // false
```

Double zeros are not empty.

Do not use `empty()` for validation. Do you know from the top of your head which values are considered "empty"? There are some surprises, and that is reason enough for me to avoid that function.

Comment: `Do not use empty() for validation` > if I know all possible `empty()` values, I shouldn't use it too? It is form validation... Why `empty()` is **bad** ?

Comment: "0" is empty, "1" is not, also "00" - inconsistent behavior for such an important task as form validation. If you want to check for non-zero string length, use `strlen()`. If you want to enforce certain content, a regular expression might be a good alternative. Whatever you use: It should explain itself without doubt. `empty()` fails this constraint.

Comment: even `empty()` might be sufficient in several non-complex conditions, if properly use it. Just do not blame the function in all sins, because, more often, humans make mistakes rather than functions.

Comment: Exactly because humans make mistakes I suggest to avoid `empty()`. This function is a known source of confusion and errors.